Selenium ChromeDriver asking to set default search engine on startup
When Selenium opens ChromeDriver. ChromeDriver asks you to select the default search engine,and won't let me access the website I need, even if I select a search engine every time it runs, it asks for it again. I've tried to run it with no first run, no default browser check, and headless options but none of them seem to work. What can I do to fix it or get around it?

Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example so that we can see exactly what you're trying to do

it is pretty simple you just need to add a new option in Chrome options as follows
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-search-engine-choice-screen")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

by adding options.add_argument("--disable-search-engine-choice-screen") you can prevent search engine selection popup.

The problem was I put no default browser insetad of no default search engine. Now it works (although obivously I'm having other problems unrelated to the question though).

This does not constitute an answer. Please delete this and then delete the original question

@SIGHUP however this does, as the fix to ChromeDriver asking to set the default search engine is adding the chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-search-engine-choice-screen"), instead of the mistake i made with the no default browser, in hind sight it is a "stupid" problem i had as it is essentially a typo, but this is the answer to the typo non the less

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
